# How to check type of object inherited from QObject in breakpoint condition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, qt

Is it possible to check type of object inherited from QObject in visual studio breakpoint condition?

Comment: Could you clarify this a little bit?   You are breaking inside a QObject function but want to know what is the class of the object that called it?

Comment: @Karlson, I would like to set a breakpoint condition on a variable type to stop only when function was called with a certain argument types.

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint where this function is called and then just step into the function.

Comment: @Karlson because there are to much entry points, thousands of them.